# How do I convert a calculated field in crystal reports into an SSRS expression?

Tags: ms-access, reporting-services, expr

I have a calculated field in crystal reports, which I need to convert it to an SSRS expression. Any help would be appreciated.

```
If ({VISIT_TYPE.DESCRIPTION} = "New" or {VISIT_TYPE.DESCRIPTION} = "Walk-In New") then
    if {ATTEND_STATUS.DESCRIPTION} = "Did Not Attend" then
        "c.New DNA"
    else
        "a.New"
else if ({VISIT_TYPE.DESCRIPTION} = "Return" or {VISIT_TYPE.DESCRIPTION} = "Follow Up" 
or {VISIT_TYPE.DESCRIPTION} = "Walk-In Follow Up" or {VISIT_TYPE.DESCRIPTION} = "Walk-In Returns") then
    if {ATTEND_STATUS.DESCRIPTION} = "Did Not Attend" then
        "d.Return DNA"
    else
        "b.Return"
```

Comment: `=IIF(condition, true, false)` in SSRS. You would need to convert your fields to SSRS dataset fields too. You should give a better formatted question as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You'll need to replace the fields with the dataset fields.

```
=IIF ({VISIT_TYPE.DESCRIPTION} = "New" or {VISIT_TYPE.DESCRIPTION} = "Walk-In New", IIF ({ATTEND_STATUS.DESCRIPTION} = "Did Not Attend" ,
        "c.New DNA","a.New")
,IIF ({VISIT_TYPE.DESCRIPTION} = "Return" or {VISIT_TYPE.DESCRIPTION} = "Follow Up" 
or {VISIT_TYPE.DESCRIPTION} = "Walk-In Follow Up" or {VISIT_TYPE.DESCRIPTION} = "Walk-In Returns",IIF({ATTEND_STATUS.DESCRIPTION} = "Did Not Attend","d.Return DNA","b.Return"))
```